# Trouble searching Low events date with Low Search

Tags: low-search, low-events

I'm using the Low Events & Low Search code sample ( https://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/search ) with the latest versions of EE, Low Search and Low events.

My Results tag filters my events by keyword correctly, how do I get it to filter by selected month-year?

`http://x.jp/index.php/show?keywords=test&low_events:date=upcoming`

`http://x.jp/index.php/show?keywords=test&low_events:date=2018-09`

`{exp:low_search:results
query="{segment_2}"
channel="show"
keywords:lang="en"
keywords:inflect="yes"
low_events:date""
}`

Sorry but I am quite new to this.  Hope someone can help.   Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `low_events:date` parameter from the Results tag, as that will override any parameters given in the query.